# Regenerating random number after guess

Tags: swift

I have a guessing game app that the user tries to guess the correct number. So far I have everything working except for my reset button so the user can play again. In my reset button function I have it setting the image and the label text back so the user starts the game over, but it doesn't seem to want to get a new random number again, it just uses the same number.

This is what I have so far...

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)//gets random number

func randomGuess()    {
    let userGuess = Int(guess.text!)
    print(randomNumber)
    if(userGuess != nil)    {
        if(Int(randomNumber) == userGuess)  {
            lblResult.text = "You win!"
            imgCandy.image = UIImage.animatedImage(with:images, duration: 1)
        } else  {
            if(Int(randomNumber) < userGuess!)   {
                lblResult.text = "Too high - guess again!"
                imgCandy.image = UIImage(named: "tooHigh.png")
            } else  {
                lblResult.text = "Too low - guess again!"
                imgCandy.image = UIImage(named: "tooLow.png")
            }
        }
    } else  {
        lblResult.text = "A number from 0-99 is required"
        imgCandy.image = UIImage(named: "gumballs.jpg")
    }
}

@IBAction func btnGuess(_ sender: Any) {
    randomGuess()
}

@IBAction func btnReset(_ sender: Any) {
    imgCandy.image = UIImage(named: "gumballs.jpg")
    lblResult.text = "Ready? Pick a number from 0-99"
    randomGuess()
}
```

Comment: Change `randomNumber` to a `var` and set its value again in `btnReset`

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `randomNumber` is a *let constant*, so it is set once and never gets changed.  Change it to a `var`:

```
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)
```

and then set it again in your `btnReset(_:)` function:

```
@IBAction func btnReset(_ sender: Any) {
    imgCandy.image = UIImage(named: "gumballs.jpg")
    lblResult.text = "Ready? Pick a number from 0-99"
    randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)
    randomGuess()
}
```